# convertir números a palabras con Python

Tags: python

estoy intentando esta función que lea un numero y retorne el mismo número pero en palabras. Llegué hasta las decenas de mil y funciona, pero cuando la decena de mil es redonda (10, 20, 30, 40 mil, etc.) no lo lee bien. Entiendo que es porque puse decenas_mil = decenas. Mi pregunta es cómo puedo hacer para que lea "diez mil, veinte mil" pero que a su vez siga leyendo como hasta ahora. Mi intención es hacer que se pueda leer entre diez y 12 dígitos. Espero que se comprenda mi pregunta. Dejo el código aquí abajo. Cualquier ayuda y/o sugerencia es bienvenida gracias.

```py
import random

def numeros_a_palabras(numero):
    if numero == 0:
        return 'Cero'
    elif numero == 1000000:
        return 'Un millon'
    
    en_palabras = ''
    
    unidades =['', 'uno','dos', 'tres', 'cuatro', 'cinco', 'seis', 'siete', 'ocho', 'nueve']
    decenas = ['', 'dieci', 'veinti', 'treinta y ', 'cuarenta y ', 'cincuenta y ', 'sesenta y ', 'setenta y ', 'ochenta y ', 'noventa y ']
    centenas = ['', 'ciento', 'doscientos', 'trescientos', 'cuatrocientos', 'quinientos', 'seiscientos', 'setecientos', 'ochocientos', 'novecientos']
    unidades_mil =['', 'un mil','dos mil', 'tres mil', 'cuatro mil', 'cinco mil', 'seis mil', 'siete mil', 'ocho mil', 'nueve mil']
    decenas_mil = decenas
    
    
    numero = '0' *(5-len(str(numero))) + str(numero)
    
    unidad = int(numero[-1])
    decena = int(numero[-2])
    centena = int(numero[-3])
    unidad_mil = int(numero[-4])
    decena_mil = int(numero[-5])
    
    # Strip saca espacio en blanco al tener menos digitos
    
    en_palabras = '{} {} {}{}'.format(unidades_mil[unidad_mil], centenas[centena], decenas[decena], unidades[unidad]).strip()
    
    if len(numero) == 5:
        en_palabras = '{}{} {} {}{}'.format(decenas_mil[decena_mil], unidades_mil[unidad_mil], centenas[centena], decenas[decena], unidades[unidad]).strip()
    
    #casos especiales a cambiar:
    
    en_palabras = en_palabras.replace('dieciuno', 'once')
    en_palabras = en_palabras.replace('diecidos', 'doce')
    en_palabras = en_palabras.replace('diecitres', 'trece')
    en_palabras = en_palabras.replace('diecicuatro', 'catorce')
    en_palabras = en_palabras.replace('diecicinco', 'quince')
    en_palabras = en_palabras.replace('uno millones', 'un millon')
    
    #cuando termina en:
    if en_palabras.endswith('dieci'):
        en_palabras = en_palabras.replace('dieci', 'diez')
    elif en_palabras.endswith('veinti'):
        en_palabras = en_palabras.replace('veinti', 'veinte')
    elif en_palabras.endswith(' y'):
        en_palabras = en_palabras[:-2]
    elif en_palabras.endswith('ciento'):
        en_palabras = en_palabras.replace('ciento', 'cien')
    
    return en_palabras.capitalize()



valor = random.randint(0,99999)
print(valor, "se escribe: ", numeros_a_palabras(valor))
```

Comment: Para hacerlo bien hay que tener en cuenta bastantes excepciones que hay que chequear una a una, así como considerar las variaciones en número y género que existen en castellano. Te recomiendo que uses algo ya hecho: https://github.com/mamcode/python-numerals

Answer (score 3):

Al probar tu código no solo daba el resultado incorrecto en lo que tu dices, sino en otras cosas más. Por eso decidí reescrbir parte de la lógica que tenías.

Primero decidí partir el problema en pequeñas partes. MI razonamiento fue el siguiente:

- ¿Cómo se divide un número?

> Pues en unidades, decenas, centenas, etc

- ¿Cómo leo un número?

> Si quiero leer 123 456 hago:
> ciento veintitrés mil cuatrocientos cincuenta y seis

-¿Hay patrones que se repitan?

> Pues sí, el número se separa por cientos y de acuerdo a su posición se le asigna la notación de cien, miles, millones, etc.

Es decir que si quiero leer 123 456 podría hacer lo siguiente

1. Separo el número de 3 en 3, quedándome ["123", "456"]
2. Leo cada número por separado, el primero sería ciento veintitrés, el segundo cuatrocientos cincuenta y seis
3. Ahora lo que me queda sería juntarlos pero con la notación correcta, si tengo 2 grupos entonces hablamos de miles, si tengo 3 de millones y así sucesivamente.

#### Aclaración

Por ahora la función funciona **perfectamente** con números de **hasta 6 cifras**

---

En base a este razonamiento (que espero se haya entendido) he escrito las siguientes funciones auxiliares:

```py
def armar_cientos(num: str) -> str:
    unidades =['', 'uno','dos', 'tres', 'cuatro', 'cinco', 'seis', 'siete', 'ocho', 'nueve']
    decenas = ['', 'dieci', 'veinti', 'treinta y ', 'cuarenta y ', 'cincuenta y ', 'sesenta y ', 'setenta y ', 'ochenta y ', 'noventa y ']
    centenas = ['', 'ciento', 'doscientos', 'trescientos', 'cuatrocientos', 'quinientos', 'seiscientos', 'setecientos', 'ochocientos', 'novecientos']
    
    cientos = int(num[0]) if len(num) > 2 else 0
    decena, unidad = num[-2:]
    return (f"{centenas[cientos]} " if cientos != 0 else '') + decenas[int(decena)] + unidades[int(unidad)]
```

Esta función se encarga de armar el grupo de centenas, decenas o unidades y devolver el resultado, lo que se le pasa por parámetro sería un string de 3 cifras.

La siguiente función es la de separa en partes de 3 el número dado.

```py
def dividir_num(num: str) -> list:
    return [num[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(num), 3)]
```

Y finalmente la función principal

```py
def numeros_a_palabras(numero:int) -> str:
    if numero == 0:
        return 'Cero'
    elif numero == 1000000:
        return 'Un millon'
    
    en_palabras = ''
    
    str_numero = str(numero)
    longitud_num = len(str_numero)

    unidades =['', 'uno','dos', 'tres', 'cuatro', 'cinco', 'seis', 'siete', 'ocho', 'nueve']
    otros = ['', 'mil', 'millon']

    casos_especiales = {
        10: "diez",
        11: "once",
        12: "doce",
        13: "trece",
        14: "catorce",
        15: "quince"
    }


    for i, parte in enumerate(dividir_num(str_numero[::-1])):
        parte = parte[::-1]
        num = int(parte)
        # print(parte)

        if num == 0: continue
        if len(str(num)) == 1: en_palabras =  unidades[num] + f"{otros[i]} " + en_palabras
        elif num > 15:
            resultado = armar_cientos(parte).strip()

            if resultado[-1] == 'i':
                resultado = resultado[:-1] + ('e' if parte[-2] == '2' else 'a')
            elif resultado == 'ciento': 
                resultado = 'cien'
            
            if i == 0: 
                en_palabras += f"{resultado} "
            else:
                en_palabras = resultado + f" {otros[i]} " + en_palabras
        else:
            en_palabras = casos_especiales[num] + f" {otros[i]} " + en_palabras
    
    if en_palabras.startswith('uno'):
        en_palabras = ('un ' if i > 1 else '') + en_palabras[3:]
    return en_palabras.strip().capitalize()
```

Lo nuevo de esta función es que define un diccionario de casos especiales, mucho mejor que una serie de `if`s anidados. Luego separa el número dado como entrada en grupo de 3 y utilizamos un ciclo `for` para recorrer las partes y junto con la función `enumerate` podemos enumerar la cantidad de partes y así poder colocar de forma correcta si son miles, millones, etc.

**Probamos**

```py
print(numeros_a_palabras(2))
print(numeros_a_palabras(100))
print(numeros_a_palabras(520))
print(numeros_a_palabras(1000))
print(numeros_a_palabras(2023))
print(numeros_a_palabras(16091))
print(numeros_a_palabras(100100))
```

**Salida**

```
Dos
Cien
Quinientos veinte
Mil
Dosmil veintitres
Dieciseis mil noventa y uno
Cien mil cien
```

Espero que esto te ayude y anime a otros a responder. Por ahora esto es todo lo que hice, en cuanto avance más editaré la respuesta.

Si tienes preguntas puedes dejarlas en los comentario :D.

Comment: Hola Christian! Gracias por ayudarme. Me ayudó mucho el razonamiento que hiciste sobre dividir los números en bloques de 3. Así es mucho más facil. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: @SaraElisaUn placer haberte ayudado. Por otra parte, puede que te interese [num2words](https://pypi.org/project/num2words/)